# display button after user choose options in multiple dropdown

Tags: jquery

I want to display button after user chooses an option in every dropdown list.
Thank's for your help.

Button

```
 <button class="generate">Generate iframe</button>
```

Dropdown lists

```
 <form id="video_selection">
     <select id="select_video1" onchange="changeVideo1()">
         <option>Vidéo 1</option>
         <?php
         foreach($id as $video1)
         {
             $videoId1 = $video1['id'];
             $videoLink1 = $video1['link'];
         ?>
         <option id="video1_iframe" value="<?php echo $videoLink1;?>"><?php echo $videoLink1;?></option>
         <?php
         }
         ?>
     </select>
     <select id="select_video2" onchange="changeVideo2()">
         <option>Vidéo 2</option>
         <?php
         foreach($id2 as $video2)
         {
             $videoId2 = $video2['id'];
             $videoLink2 = $video2['link'];
         ?>
         <option id="video2_iframe" value="<?php echo $videoLink2;?>"><?php echo $videoLink2;?></option>
         <?php
         }
         ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: see fiddle for update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code will be something along the lines of:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var unselected = $('select').filter(function() {
    return this.selectedIndex <= 0;
  });
  if (unselected.length) return;
  $('.generate').show();
});
```

```css
.generate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
<button class="generate">Generate iframe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think T J code is very good, but you have to put empty values as first choice, as no choice has been made at page load.

Here is a simple jsfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/mantisse_fr/72sp6vn4/

```
// If an empty value is still selected, don't go further to show the generate button
// and if the button was there, hide it.
if (unselected.length!==0) { $(".generate").hide(); return; };
```

code completed with hide functionnality at page load and if the user selects an empty value (needed for page load).